# Why is "symbol lookup error" not caught at compile-time?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm updating some old code, and accidentally left a macro inside that's no longer defined:

```
// "DETAIL" is not defined anywhere
if (DETAIL ("notebook")) {
    // ...
}
```

The code still compiles and links (its a .so library), but when it is loaded I get:

```
gtk3-widget-factory: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/
theming-engines/libmurrine.so: undefined symbol: DETAIL
```

**Why isn't this caught at compile time?** I guess C sees `DETAIL` without any definition and assumes it is a function `int -> int` , right? Is there any way to make the compiler (gcc) be more strict and complain at compile time? I don't think I'm directly using any symbols without definition in my source or header files.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to compile an executable with the code (the linker would fail), but in a library code with undefined functions still link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is correct: `DETAIL` is treated as an implicitly-defined function.

From the [`gcc` manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> `-Wimplicit-function-declaration (C and Objective-C only)`
>
> Give a warning whenever a function is used before being declared. In C99 mode (`-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99`), this warning is enabled by default and it is made into an error by `-pedantic-errors`. This warning is also enabled by `-Wall`.

Additionally, as @Jonathan Leffler points out in the comments:

> Also, in some versions of GCC, it's an error with `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` (and similarly for any other explicit warning option). All warnings can be converted to errors with `-Werror`.

Comment: Also, in some versions of GCC, it's an error with `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` (and similarly for any other explicit warning option).  All warnings can be converted to errors with `-Werror`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Great comment, thanks. I've taken the liberty to incorporate it into the answer.